# AngularJS use returned boolean from directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a class called `late` that I'd like to apply conditionally:

```
<div ng-class="late: isLate"></div>
```

I have a directive called `isLate` that performs a calculation and returns a boolean. What is the right way to link these two? I searched the directive documentation and didn't find anything that does this. Maybe using directives isn't the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first move your calculation from directive to scope:

```
$scope.isLate = function() {
  // make calculations here and return bool value 
}
```

And then pass object to ng-class directive:

```
<div ng-class="{late: isLate()}"></div>
```

For each key-value pair of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class name. (from ngClass docs)

Comment: This works. My impression was the directives are better than ```$scope.function()``` but this works.

Answer (score 0):

For ng-class you need to provide an object that is used as a map with the class name mapped to some expression that evaluates to a boolean condition. (other use cases exist but this is closest to what you're showing).

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

so something like this would work assuming that isLate was a boolean on your controller scope

```
<div ng-class="{'late':isLate}"></div>
```

I don't know that a directive is the right approach here since they are generally used for adding behavior and DOM manipulation.  Or rather I don't think that using a directive within the ng-class is the right approach, though perhaps just having a custom directive that you use as an attribute on the DOM element could work.